# Is it possible to crack a 2FA/MFA secret key provided you know enough of the previous generated codes?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, reverse-engineering

I have two accounts that won't show me the 2FA/MFA "Secret Key" used to generate the multifactor codes. Because of this, I am forced to use specific MFA apps rather than my preferred one. If I had the secret key, I could get rid of the other apps and use my preferred generator.

Given I have access to all the generated codes, is it possible to reverse the generation to obtain the secret key?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, not if it's properly implemented.**

---

Details

2FA token apps are typically [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password) or [HOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-based_one-time_password#Definition) which, at their core, are an HMAC with your token secret *K* and a counter *C* (which could be a timestamp in TOTP or an actual counter in HOTP).

```
HOTP(K, C) = truncate(HMAC(K, C)),
```

What you are describing is a known ciphertext attack, which HMAC is resistant to.

Reference:

- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8500/with-hmac-can-an-attacker-recover-the-key-given-many-known-plaintext-tag-pairs

You could, of course do the brute force attack: capture an OTP value at a known time *C* and write a program to guess secret keys *K* until you get the same OTP, but expect that program will need to run for several centuries before it guesses correctly.